# Open source tool to generate generic DDL scripts

Tags: mysql, hsqldb, ddl

I have to **generate generic DDL scripts** from a running MySQL database (source) that will be run on a HSQLDB database (target) and I am therefore looking for an open source tool that could generate generic DDL scripts (or at least as generic as possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd check first the [`--no-data`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-data) and [`--compatible=name`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_compatible) options of [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html).